# Get data from an API for Chartist in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, api, angular, promise, observable

I'm trying to build a chart with Chartist with data coming from my Node.js API. In the doc of Chartist there is an example of async data like this :

```
class AsyncChartComponent {
  data: Promise<Chartist.IChartistData>;
  type: Promise<ChartType>;

  constructor() {
    // simulate slow API call
    this.data = new Promise(function(resolve: any): void {
      setTimeout(function(): void {
        resolve(data['Pie']);
      }, 5000);
    });

    this.type = new Promise(function(resolve: any): void {
      setTimeout(function(): void {
        resolve('Pie');
      }, 5000);
    });
  }
}
```

But I get my data from API using `Observable` and I'm not able to deal with the `Promise` and the `Observable`...
I try to `resolve` my `Promise` with the data from my call to the API but nothing is returned expect the `Observable`. I'm not sure how I have to deal with this :s
Here is my Angular 2 component :

```
export class RatesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() changed = new EventEmitter<IRate>();

  rates: IRate[] = [];
  selectedRate: IRate;
  errorMessage: string;
  chart: Chart;
  chartData: Promise<Chartist.IChartistData>;
  type = 'Line';

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getRates()
        .subscribe(
          (data: IRate[]) => {
            this.rates = data;
          },
          (error) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );

    this.chartData = new Promise((resolve: any): void => {
      resolve(this.dataService.getChartData());
    });

    this.dataService.getChartData()
        .subscribe(
          (data: Chartist.IChartistData) => {
            return data;
            // console.log(this.chartData);
          },
          (error) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );

    this.chart = {
      type: 'Line',
      data: JSONdata['Line2']
    };
  }

  select(rate: IRate) {
    this.selectedRate = rate;
    this.changed.emit(rate);
  }
}
```

Maybe that I should use `Promise` to call my API instead of `Observable` but I don't see how it would resolve my problem...

Any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.chartData = new Promise((resolve: any): void => {
   this.dataService.getChartData().subscribe((data: Chartist.IChartistData) => {
     resolve(data);
   },
     (error) => this.errorMessage = <any>error;
   );
});
```

You can also try this:

```
this.chartData = this.dataService.getChartData().toPromise();
```

Comment: It seems to work in both case but I've got this error :

``EXCEPTION: data.normalized.series[seriesIndex].forEach is not a function``

Comment: I don't think that's connected to this question, you might want to check your data. It looks like some of the elements of your series are not an array and therefore can't use the forEach function.

Comment: Why when I create a reload function executing the same way, I got an empty ``Promise`` ?
    ``reloadChart() {
        this.chartData = this.dataService.getChartData().toPromise();
      }``

Comment: What does getChartData() return?

Comment: An ``Observable``

```getChartData(): Observable<Chartist.IChartistData> {
    return this.http.get(this.urlChartData)
                    .map((resp: Response) => resp.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }```

Comment: I meant at runtime, but thanks for the code. :) Does the request goes through?

Comment: Yes the request goes through because I see it in my Node.js app  API.

Comment: That's really weird behaviour, I tried running a sort of same code and everything works fine for me.

Comment: Thank's for your help I will keep trying to understant what happen... The link of the source : https://github.com/Hugo-Contreras/angularPOC